# Removing colons from variable values

Tags: r, string

Working in R, I have a series of values that include colons (e.g., Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes). I would like to remove them so the value is still there except the colon (e.g., Electronic Smoke Participant Yes). The code I have written to set up this test is below:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(dplyr)

x<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d","e","e","e","f", "f", "f", 
     "g","g","g","h","h", "h")

y<-rep(c("Circulatory: Circulatory Conditions", "Smoking: 100 Cigs Lifetime", 
     "Electronic Smoking: Electric Smoke Participant"),8)

z<-c("Circulatory Conditions: Atrial Fibrillation", "100 Cigs Lifetime: No", "Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Atrial Fibrillation", "100 Cigs Lifetime: Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Atrial Fibrillation", "100 Cigs Lifetime: No", "Electronic Smoke Participant: No",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Stroke", "100 Cigs Lifetime: No", "Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Stroke", "100 Cigs Lifetime: Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes",
     "Circulatory Conditions: High Cholesterol", "100 Cigs Lifetime: Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant: Yes",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Pulmonary Embolism", "100 Cigs Lifetime: No", "Electronic Smoke Participant: No",
     "Circulatory Conditions: Heart Attack", "PMI: Skip", "PMI: Prefer Not To Answer"
     )

## Combine all objects, label, and tibble

test<-cbind(x,y,z)
colnames(test)<-c("part_id", "question", "answer")
data<-as_tibble(test)
data


# Here we take the long dataset and make it wide
data<-data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=question, values_from=answer) 

head(data)

# Put data into data frame from tibble
data<-data.frame(data)
head(data)


# Remove colons
data <- gsub(':','',data)
data

data<-str_remove_all(data, ":")
data
```

I have tried both gsub and str_replace_all (and str_remove_all), but they both seem to add in RegEx stuff that I don't want in there (output is as follows):

[4] "c("Electronic Smoke Participant Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant No", "Electronic Smoke Participant Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant Yes", "Electronic Smoke Participant No", "PMI Prefer Not To Answer")"

In addition, a dim on this object (data) returns a NULL.

Comment: `gsub` and `str_remove` and `str_replace` all expect to work on 1 vector (or 1 column) at a time, not a whole data frame.

Answer (score 3):

Functions like `gsub` and `str_remove` and `str_replace` expect their input to be a vector (column), not a whole data frame.

With `dplyr`'s `across()` we can apply these functions to multiple columns in one command. I'd recommend removing the colons *before* you pivot the data so you only have to remove them from the column values, not the column names as well:

```
test = test %>% mutate(across(c(question, answer), \(x) str_remove_all(x, ":")))
test
#    part_id                                      question                                     answer
# 1        a            Circulatory Circulatory Conditions Circulatory Conditions Atrial Fibrillation
# 2        a                     Smoking 100 Cigs Lifetime                       100 Cigs Lifetime No
# 3        a Electronic Smoking Electric Smoke Participant           Electronic Smoke Participant Yes
# 4        b            Circulatory Circulatory Conditions Circulatory Conditions Atrial Fibrillation
# 5        b                     Smoking 100 Cigs Lifetime                      100 Cigs Lifetime Yes
# 6        b Electronic Smoking Electric Smoke Participant           Electronic Smoke Participant Yes
# 7        c            Circulatory Circulatory Conditions Circulatory Conditions Atrial Fibrillation
#...
```

Comment: +1, just a heads up that the use of `...` in `across` is [soft-deprecated in 1.1.0](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#newly-deprecated-1-1-0).

Comment: Thanks for the note - I'm still using 1.0.10 and I'm not looking forward to that change :\

Comment: Agreed! They must have their reasons though, but your post is a good example of where I think `...` is cleaner/easier to read.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you so much! That worked like a charm! And great idea to do this earlier in the script rather than later, saved me some headaches later on I think.

Comment: @JamesClifford glad to hear it worked. If you consider your question resolved, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark in the left margin next to it.